# Can you craft maps of the Nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So [we know](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23339/when-is-the-map-location-and-zoom-level-set) that a maps location is based on the first time you *look* at it, but can you craft a map of the Nether?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, but they don't do you much good.  From [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Map_%28Item%29#Usage):

> While maps in the Nether work, it has
> a ceiling, and all that will be shown
> is red and gray. The only useful
> function is finding where you are in
> relation to where you made the map.
> Additionally, the direction indicator
> rapidly spins and is not a good
> indicator of direction. Remembering
> that maps are East at the top and that
> the L corner of nether blocks points
> north is more reliable. And as long as
> the map was created near a portal,
> that map's center will always be that
> portal.

Comment: That would be pretty good, to be fair. You can see where you are in relation to your portal.

Comment: @The Yes, I guess that could be useful. I'll have to map the nether to see if it is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You can break the ceiling of the Nether (although getting there is only safe in Creative), so if you break the ceiling the map might map out the actual landscape. I haven't tried this, but I think it would work well.

Comment: If you have your own question, you should ask in a different question, not put it in an answer here. And your answer doesn't seem to add anything that is not stated or inferred from the accepted answer.