# How can I create a farm in the Nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just joined a multiplayer server and want to make a village in the Nether.

Is it possible to create farms for growing food and trees there? If so, how  could I go about doing it?

Comment: I have edited your question to sound less "Chatty and open-ended". Please read this part of the [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) for what not to ask

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I survive in the Nether long enough to build shelter?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10144/how-do-i-survive-in-the-nether-long-enough-to-build-shelter)

Comment: @MarkTrapp I'd say not a duplicate, as this is about surviving for "more than a few seconds", while this one is about packing up and moving to Netherland indefinitely. That presents very different challenges, and makes it considerably less than "exactly" the same.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Easily fixed by editing: it's not important to the question, and the answers specifically answered the general question of surviving in the nether. We do not need multiple questions duplicating the exact same information.

Comment: @MarkTrapp None of those other answers address growing food or trees, which means they don't answer this question. Correct answers to this question won't duplicate information.

Comment: @MarkTrapp [Here's an important policy blog post about non-exact duplicates being *good* for the site.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) If you haven't read it yet, it will explain why I'm against your proposal to edit them to match so that this one can be closed.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'm aware of the "Dr. Strangedupe" blog post. It's *not* policy: [it's a guideline](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/#comment-51990). In *this* specific case, directing a new user to a comprehensive question and answer pair is *better* than than slavishly holding to the idea that the words are not exactly the same as the previous question, ignoring its existence, and letting this question sit around unanswered.

Comment: @MarkTrapp I think the existence of the other question has been made abundantly clear.

Comment: @kotekzot Not sure what the point of your comment is. It's been made clear because I left a single comment. Mission accomplished: there was nothing more to be said. The rest of this is just SevenSidedDie's annoyance with said comment.

Comment: @MarkTrapp is that why you suggested editing the question to make it a dupe?

Comment: @kotekzot It *is*, as currently worded, a dupe, edits or not. The wording SevenSidedDie objected to had no bearing on the question or its answers and was easily fixed.

Comment: One way this could be rewritten would be to only ask about the parts not yet covered by the other question ([as SevenSidedDie noted](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81849/tips-for-long-term-survival-in-the-nether#comment113303_81849)): instead of "Tips for long-term survival in the nether", how about "How do I create a farm in the nether?"

Comment: @MarkTrapp …Then do that? Or just leave it, 'cause it already focuses on that? Closing is a last resort, and if you agree the intent of this question isn't a duplicate then I don't even know why this debate happened.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie As I've repeatedly said, it *was* as worded, a duplicate of the earlier question. Closing is *not* a last resort: closing is an interim state to fix the problems with a post. I commented rather than editing again since you seemed to have an issue with people editing questions to fix things, but since you're fine with it, it's done.

Comment: …Um. No, closing for the reason that something is a duplicate is not "interim", it's intended to be permanent. I'm going to get off this train at this stop now, since it seems to be going to goalpost-moving town.

Answer (score 15):

According to [the Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/The_Nether#Nether-affected_materials)

> Trees grow normally, and their leaves take a dead-looking brownish
> color like in desert biomes.

So trees can be grown as normal (as long as you are careful about making sure that lava doesn't just burn them all down), however

> There is no way to place water in the Nether in a Survival game

Placing water source blocks with the bucket causes the water to instantly evaporate (with a hissing sound). You can still grow wheat in the Nether, however it will grow very slowly without water (also see the [Wheat](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wheat) page on the wiki).

This also makes growing sugar cane impossible, however I believe that growing [Pumpkin](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pumpkin) and [Melon](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Melon_%28Block%29) is largely unaffected by this as water only affects the rate at which the stem grows (which can be sped up with bonemeal), not the rate at which the Melon and Pumpkin themselves spawn.  (The wiki does mention that Pumpkin cannot be grown in [The End](https://minecraft.wiki/w/The_End), but doesn't mention the Nether.  I believe that Melon should grown there successfully but I haven't verified this).

Finally

> Overworld mobs like pigs and zombies do not randomly spawn in the Nether, but throwing chicken eggs and constructing golems works as normal

So you will be unable to breed cows or pigs for food without using mods, however you can breed chickens by throwing eggs.

Its also worth mentioning that [Nether Wart](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Wart) *only* spawns in the Nether, but can be grown in the overworld if you take a block of Soul sand with you.

Comment: Addendum: That's as of Version 1.3.2. In Version 1.4 (and current test builds), entities aside from the player(s) will get teleported through the nether portals, so you will be able to bring pigs, cows, wolves and so on with you.

Comment: Since [12w27a](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Version_history/Development_versions#12w27a) Nether Wart can actually grow in the Overworld and The End.

Comment: Wheat will grow in the nether, but you have to be quick to plant it.

Comment: There is a loophole that previously allowed water in the nether.  Ice blocks mined with silk touch before it was nerfed and placed in the nether before the 1.3 release would melt into water source blocks.  reference: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8u5LaLOMB70

Comment: Growing of pumpkin and melon blocks is now also affected by growth rate of the stem. As of 1.8.6, they attempt to grow with the same rate as the stem itself attempts to grow...

Answer (score 3):

The Minecraft wiki states (I've tried only wheat and watermelon) that all farmland crops can be grown in the Nether (growth speed is decreased). The only thing you have to remember is that once you gather your crops you have to immediately replant them. Otherwise because of the missing water (as stated from others here you can't have water source blocks on the ground in the Nether needed to grow sugar cane and speed up the growth of other crops) the dirt will revert to its default state and you have to use a hoe to make it suitable for farming again.

Personally I think that watermelons are the best food source in the Nether if I'm down there for a long time and my baked potato supplies diminish. Take some dirt with you and put the blocks in a safe location in the Nether (a stone house will do the trick, since Ghats can't blow stone blocks up). Use a hoe to turn the dirt into farmland and plant the watermelon seeds. Use bonemeal to speed up the growing. The special thing about watermelons and pumpkins is that once you plant the seed the ground doesn't reverse to its default state (in which you can't plant seeds in it). Pumpkins and watermelons are the only ones that produce "fruit" at the same speed as in the Overworld (tried it myself!), since the only thing that takes longer to grow in the Nether is the stem. Unlike wheat for example, which has to be replanted after gathered, pumpkins/melons provide infinite food once you have fully grown their stems. Pumpkins however are only useful in the Nether if you want Jack'o'Lanterns. It is not possible to create the recently added Pumpkin pie recipe without sugar cane and sugar cane grows only next to water blocks.

Here is a great tutorial for a fully automated watermelon/pumpkin farm by monkeyfarm:

I have a couple of those in the Overworld and they work great. The only problem is that they require plenty of resources and such that can be found only in the Overworld (iron, stone, redstone, sand (for glass; not Nether sand!)). But once you have build and secured it in the Nether, it will give you PLENTY of food.

Trees are also not that difficult to grow. You need some light sources, a safe location (note that making a huge room for your trees doesn't mean Ghasts won't spawn in it so be careful and take extra care!), dirt and tree stems. Growth rate is again the same as in the Overworld! You can produce tools (axes, hoes, shovels etc.), charcoals, torches and so on so it's essential to have a decent tree farm in the Nether if you want to stay there for a longer period of time.

Comment: Why not? It's not really bad to have ghasts in your house.(this happens very rarely). If you don't let them fire it's even better. You can even get ghast tears.

Comment: The probability of a ghast seeing you and NOT firing is very, very small. I have nothing against ghasts but the same way you don't want any creepers among your crops that you really need to survive in the long run, you don't want something that can shoot exploding fireballs at you creating huge holes in the ground and setting things on fire. Just sayin...

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you can grow crops in Nether(at least wheat). Crops can grow without water at a slow rate.(Note:You cannot place water in Nether,and farmland will transform into dirt if it has neither water nor crops in it(I am sure that it applies at least to wheat crops),according to the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/farmland). Trees can grow normally,but they can be set on fire by lava. Just make sure that you bring dirt and seeds/saplings. And now about the village,just build some houses with at least 5×5 space horizontally. (I'm not sure about the height,but for maximum succes chance,put 5 spaces vertically. Then,bring some villagers through the portal,either from a village or from curing a zombie to populate the village.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply take cow on the lead, bring very close to the portal, and teleport yourself to the Nether. Cow should be teleported with you, but lead probably don't, so take minimum 2 leads per cow. I haven't tried with sheep or pigs, but it should work too.

Answer (score 0):

This is an updated answer for 1.16 Minecraft. Judging by the fact you are beginning on a multiplayer server, my assumption is that you are in the Overworld. To my knowledge, wheat, mushrooms, pumpkins, and watermelon can all grow in the Nether, just at slower rates. You need dirt for all of these of course. 1.16 has added Crimson and Warped Trees, so your wood needs are fulfilled, but you can still grow regular trees in the Nether. For native livestock, you can make a Hoglin farm, which is on the more dangerous side but still functional if you get enough Crimson Fungus and can either kill them from afar or take some hits.